# typescript TS2339: Property 'phoneType' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object declared as below:

```
export class Card {
   private _phones:Object[]

    get phones(): Object[]{
        if(this._phones === undefined)
            this._phones = []

        return this._phones
    }

    set phones(val:Object[]){
        this._phones = val
    }
}
```

somewhere in my html my code looks like

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let phone of card.phones">
                  <ng-container *ngIf="phone.type === 'personal'">
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100%">
```

The above code throws the compilation error:

```
Error: src/app/process-card/process-card.component.html:128:46 - error TS2339: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Object'.

128                   <ng-container *ngIf="phone.type === 'personal'">
```

I do understand the issue that my card type is of object and phone.type cannot be determined. However, instead of creating an interface to bypass this is there any other workaround?

Comment: Use `any` type rather `Object`.

Comment: "*instead of creating an interface*" why?

Comment: Why do you use typescript if you don't want to use its benefits?

Comment: So  i have this code that was written 2-3 years ago and was on a very old version. now i can no longer compile and deploy it to firebase etc. so after failing to upgrade it as is i had to create a new project with latest angular version etc. and at this point my goal is to first get up and running as is.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid 'any' in your code. Couple of possible solutions is below:

```
interface PhoneInterface {
  type: string;
}

export class Card {
  private _phones: PhoneInterface[]
  ....
}
```

Or:

```
interface HasTypeProperty {
  type: string;
}

export class Card<T extends HasTypeProperty> {
  private _phones: T[];
      ....
}
```